# Text Area and Null, Laravel Collective

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6, laravel-blade, laravelcollective

I've been using Laravel Collective for my forms and I seem to have encountered an issue with textareas. One that won't let me update null textarea fields with the same code I would use for a text field. I think the issue is with 'null' as it allows me to change the field if the textarea has text loaded. Does anyone know how to fix this so I can change null fields with textareas?

```
{!! Form::label ('otherinfo', 'Other information:') !!}
{!! Form::textarea ('otherinfo', null, array('class' => 'form-control', 'required' => '', 'maxlength' =>'1500') ) !!}
```

Comment: What if you use an empty string instead? Changing `null` to `''`.

Comment: Still the same, doesn't allow me to save

Comment: use it [LaraForm1](https://github.com/omnicode/lara-form/tree/dev-1.0) or [LaraForm2](https://github.com/omnicode/lara-form/tree/dev-2.0)  for laravel 5.5+

Comment: What error message your getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should work fine. Make sure you update your Controller to accept and save the value that is present in `$request->input('otherinfo')`.

```
<?php
    $otherinfo = 'Hello World';
?>

<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('otherinfo', 'Other information:') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('otherinfo', $otherinfo, ['class' => 'form-control', 'size' => '50x3']) !!}
</div>
```